# Upgrade to springboot 2.6.1 with querydsl jpa 5.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to upgrade my springboot version from 2.3.4 to 2.6.1. I use query dsl with jpa and apt-maven-plugin. My issue is that I can't no more generate the QClasses when I run maven compile. I noticed that I am no more able to use an older version of querydsl (previous one 4.4.0 and apt-maven-plugin 1.1.3). Now when I try to use the 4.4.0 I have an error :

> Non-resolvable import POM: com.querydsl:querydsl-bom:pom:4.4.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

And then when I switch to the 5.0.0 version I have an other error :

> [INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ gof-referentiel-backend ---
> [WARNING] The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-244
> /home/ezek/Documents/projects/gof-referentiel-backend/src/main/java/fr/ubordeaux/gof/referentiel/common/persistence/dao/impl/ContactDAOImpl.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
> import fr.ubordeaux.gof.referentiel.common.persistence.entity.QContactEntity;
> ^
> symbol:   class QContactEntity
> location: package fr.ubordeaux.gof.referentiel.common.persistence.entity
> /home/ezek/Documents/projects/gof-referentiel-backend/src/main/java/fr/ubordeaux/gof/referentiel/common/persistence/dao/impl/ContactDAOImpl.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
> private static final QContactEntity qContactEntity = QContactEntity.contactEntity;

I get this error for all the classes that use entities. And nothing is generated.

Here is are the relevant values of my pom.xml :

> ```
> > <dependency>
> >      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
> >      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
> >      <version>${querydsl.version}</version> 
> > </dependency> 
> > <dependency>
> >      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
> >      <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
> >      <version>${querydsl.version}</version> 
> > </dependency>
> > 
> > <plugin>
> >      <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
> >      <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
> >      <version>1.1.3</version>
> >      <executions>
> >          <execution>
> >              <phase>generate-sources</phase>
> >              <goals>
> >                  <goal>process</goal>
> >              </goals>
> >              <configuration>
> >                  <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>      
> > 
> >                      <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
> >              </configuration>
> >           </execution>
> >      </executions> 
> ></plugin>
> ```

I also use mapstruct and lombok if maybe it is related (but I don't think) because the apt-maven-plugin runs before them.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.6.1 supports querydsl 5.0.0 out-of-the-box. So remove the `version` tag and let Spring Boot manage that. I suspect that you can remove the `phase` as well from the plugin. Finally the `querydsl-apt` dependency can be scoped with provided. Trying to use all those different processors (lombok, mapstruct and querydsl) together can be a painful process. Especially the use of lombok as that does things that offically aren't allowed to be done.

Comment: Also the "error" is a warning not an error. Check your dependencies for `commons-io` and use the proper location.

Comment: I managed to remove the warning and remove the querydsl version but still get the same result. The error is same as under the warining

Comment: Enable debugging on running maven and check what is happening. I wouldn't be suprised that this would be caused by Lombok.

Comment: But I don't know should lombok run before or after querydsl. I know that in the previous version it was after but maybe...

Comment: Lombok with querydsl can fail sometimes in generating QClasses. I fixed it previously with this plugin. Give it a try - https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl

Comment: How are you using this plugin with maven ? I was not able to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're still (perhaps transitively) relying on some Querydsl 4.0.0 dependencies. You need to remove those (I can't point out which ones, because you didn't include the full POM in your snippet).

I also recommend getting rid of the plugin altogether and instead using the dependency classifier:

```xml
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version> 
      <classifier>jpa</classifier>
      <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${querydsl.version}</version> 
 </dependency>
```

Comment: By getting rid of the plugin you mean remove the apt-maven-plugin ?

Comment: yes. Its not needed.

Comment: How do I generate the QClasses during build ? can you give an example ?

Comment: When using the proper classifier, QClasses are generated during the regular compile phase.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling it does not work for me. After removing maven apt plugin, and leaving only querydsl-apt and querydsl-jpa dependencies (with jakarta classifier) maven compiler plugin throws exception with whole banch of 'cannot find symbol' pointing out for missing QClasses. And that is correct, as at this point they are not generated. Any tips?